# Where to find the data sheet for Huawei Honor 6 smartphone?

Tags: power-supply, datasheet, android, charging, cellphone

The smartphone seems to have bq24190 chip for power and charging control (according to `/sys/`), for which the data sheet specifies that it can be powered not only from USB's 5V, but also from up to 18V.

Does it mean I can charge my Huawer Honor 6 directly from 12V? Where to find the absolute maximum ratings for a smartphone?

Comment: The reality is the manufacture is not going to tell you it can be charged from 12V, even if it won't hurt anything. They want all the sheeple using it to charge it from the supplied power brick.

Comment: How safe is to try to gradually increase input voltage while monitoring current to "probe" the actual maximum? For example, my previous smartphone just refused to start charging if input voltage is 6V.

Comment: Is it worth trying to send them a letter and ask directly?

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by charging from 12V? It's not going to be any faster.

Comment: @MattYoung, I can use DIY unregulated battery chargers more easily. For example, using stand-alone 12V car battery as super-power-bank. Why chain buck regulator with another buck regulator in the phone itself?

Comment: I really don't see why you would want to do that. It has a microUSB port. If you have unregulated chargers with microUSB connections, you should toss them, before they break something.

Comment: Before I had a proper power bank, I used just 4 serially connected NiMH batteries. Voltage can float from 4V to 6V there... Sometimes my old smartphone refused to charge because of too many volts. (And I rarely toss away electronic things, I sometimes disassemble them and re-assemle into something even creepier)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing like "datasheet for phone".

Phone is consumer electronics. Consumer doesn't have to know all these things. All you can/should get from manufacturer is manual (that usually says: "use original battery charger").

**I would not recommend trying to power phone from 12V even if you are sure that there is BQ24190** chip, because **you don't know what else is there**. Maybe some zener diode that will blow up without any other damage, maybe some extra ESD protection designed for 5V and you will destroy whole ESD circuitry).